# jQuery scrollTop troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a quiz web ap with an opening heading and then 10 questions that follow it. The div of the opening and the div of each question are all siblings, so I traverse the page by passing current.nextSibling and current.previousSibling to whatever functions I'm using.

Right now I'm trying to create a smooth scroll with jQuery through its 'animate' and 'scrollTop' methods, but it's not working. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Code attached here, link to fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fjydnc9m/1/

```
var main = function () {
    var root = $('html, body');
    var current = document.getElementById("opening");


    $('.upButton').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$(current.previousSibling).offset().top}, 2000);
        current = current.previousSibling;
    });


    $('.downButton').click(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(current.nextSibling).offset().top}, 2000);
       current = current.nextSibling;
    });



}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: when I say its not working I mean nothing happens when i click my down button, with the class ".downButton", and the same with the other button classed ".upButton"

Comment: Please put the real code and not an image. This will ensure better readability for everyone.

Comment: or even better, please provide a jsfiddle!

Comment: done and done! :) @Connum and Erick

Comment: if anyone has any other suggestions regarding my html, css, or js, whether it be direct improvements or adjustments for cleanliness/streamlining of the page, feel free to add those as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been trying to use jQuery `.offset()` on a regular HTML DOM element.
See this updated version of the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fjydnc9m/12/

What I did is to get the prev and next sibling via jQuery and use `.offset()` on that.

Note that you'll also have to account for the cases where `current` is the first or last wrapper, or some strange scrolling will take place. You can do this by checking if the length of `prevSibling` or `nextSibling` is > 0 before scrolling.

Comment: Oh right on, works like a charm. So can you real quick explain what it was I was doing wrong/you did correctly conceptually here? more specifically, what're the restriction on what I can use jQuery on? From what I can see you used a jQuery selector, assigned that to a variable, and used that variable in the jQuery functions. Is that the standard way to use jQuery on regular DOM elements?

Comment: You cannot use jQuery functions on regular DOM elements, you'll have to wrap them with `$(element)` first.

Saving it to a variable and re-using that is just a way to improve performance. Everything you do with jQuery adds a little overhead - we're talking milliseconds for basic operations, but it adds up. So it's always a good idea to save anything you need more than once into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you log the `current` variable, you find out that there is a `#text` sibling that is assigned to the `current` variable.

Check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fjydnc9m/13/

You can see that I assigned the `current` variable **twice PRIOR** to using it in the `scrollTop` function:

```
var main = function() {
var root = $('html, body');
var current = document.getElementById("opening");


 $('.upButton').click(function() {
  current = current.previousSibling;
  current = current.previousSibling;
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(current).offset().top
  }, 2000);
  console.log(current);
 });


 $('.downButton').click(function() {
  current = current.nextSibling;
  current = current.nextSibling;
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(current).offset().top
  }, 2000);
  console.log(current);
  });
 }

 $(document).ready(main);
```

Note that I'm logging the current variable. Remove one of the `current` assignments and see what the log shows (you will see what's going on).